# Is there a way to insert products through the spread sheet programmatically?

Tags: import, csv

Is there a way to send products into magento or edit them in any way programmatically without going through the API.

I understand one can load products and edit products by putting them in a spread sheet, then load that spreadsheet into magento manually.
If I have a spread sheet on my computer, is there a way to send it to magento through curl or what have you?

I ask because I'm currently spitting 100 or so records up using the api_v1 multi call, and while it works I have 10,000 products and my client would like to see what got sent, and what failed. Using the API is fine for my app, but If I could push my products into a CSV my client would be happier.

Answer (score 2):

You can use magentos dataflow for this, or a tool called magmi (magmi will be faster).

I have not used magmi myself, but I hear good things about it.

Thus, if you are using magento's built in dataflow, you would use the importer profile located under System->import/export->Dataflow Profiles. You will find product Import profile there.

It will allow you to upload the file from admin, and initiate the import via admin.

Alternatively, you can also schedule this import. There are enough examples via google search on how to run a profile via cron, just do a google.

Thus using the cron runner (lets say it runs every 5 hours), you can drop files via ftp into a folder, and via the cron initiate the importer to import any files in the folder.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Good answer! But instead of Dataflow you should use ImportExport. It does nearly the same but is a lot faster. You find it here: `System > Import/Export > Import` But this can afaik not be used with a cron, so you need a little script to write your own cron.

Comment: The really hard bit is that I can't write scripts because I've not direct access with the magento box. currently I use api-v1/multicall to get things in, but I have been considering alternatives, because the client wants to see "files".

Comment: So not just your hands are chopped off, but your legs and your head ;) Do you have access to the admin? Your only way forward then is to use the admin importers as suggested. Create csv, upload via admin, import via admin. Warning : this is really slow way to import, but may be faster than the API.